# QCPAxisTickerTime Error

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

I'm using QtcustomPlot but when I tried to change the Y axis to Datetime Axis by Class QCPAxisTickerTime, I got this error. I included QSharedPointer library. Does everyone know that and please help me.

I'm using Qt5.8.0 and QCustomPlot version 2.0.0 beta.

```
error: ‘QCPAxisTickerTime’ was not declared in this scope    
QSharedPointer<QCPAxisTickerTime> timeTicker(new QCPAxisTickerTime);
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: You should share some code as well.

Comment: I had the same problem when using QCustomPlot v1.3.2, once i switched to 2.0.0 beta it worked just fine, to be sure you have the correct version: open qcustomplot.cpp and find `QCPAxisTickerTime`

Answer (score 0):

```
QSharedPointer<QCPAxisTickerTime> timeTicker(new QCPAxisTickerTime);
timeTicker->setTimeFormat("%h:%m:%s");
trend->CustomPlot->xAxis->setTicker(timeTicker);

QSharedPointer<QCPAxisTickerTime> timeTicker2(new QCPAxisTickerTime);
timeTicker2->setTimeFormat("%h:%m:%s");
trend->CustomPlot->yAxis->setTicker(timeTicker2);
```

This worked for me.